# Превью XML в Android Studio выдает No Device Found

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, adb

Превью XML файла в Android Studio выдает это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это происходит только в layout/layout-normal и других второстепенных лаяутах. **При этом превью главного layout-а работает исрправно**. **В системе много виртуальных девайсов с разными размерами экранов**, так что по сути этого не должно происходить. Прошу помочь решить проблему. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пробовал переустановить Android Studio. Не помогло

Comment: Все ли работает? Вопрос решен ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно переустановить андройд студио или почистить кеш. Сталкивался с этим , это давний баг. Если не поможет установите другую версию. Попробуйте обновить пакеты ( sudo apt-get update ) . Если не поможет рекомендую пересесть на другую версию студии.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли! Вопрос решен.